# Is $x=-1$ a Vertical tangent or Asymptote to the curve $f(x)=\frac{(x-1)^2}{x+1}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, analytic-geometry

Is $x=-1$ a Vertical tangent or Asymptote to the curve $f(x)=\frac{(x-1)^2}{x+1}$

I have a little confusion about the difference between VT and Asymptote

we have

$$f'(x)=1-\frac{4}{(x+1)^2}$$  so

$$ \lim _{x \to -1^+} f'(x) \to - \infty$$ and

$$ \lim _{x \to -1^-} f'(x) \to - \infty$$ and

So at $x=-1$ $f(x)$ has VT.

Also by definition of asymptote we have

$$ \lim_{x \to -1^+} f(x) \to \infty$$ and

$$  \lim_{x \to -1^-} f(x) \to -\infty$$

hence  $x=-1$ is Vertical Asymptote.

so is this correct?

Comment: At $x=-1$ $f(x)$ is *not* defined, i.e. there's no  point on the representative curve with abscissa $-1$. How could it have a tangent at a point which does not exist?

Comment: ok but for $y=\frac{1}{x}$ we say $x=0$ and $y=0$ are asymptotes right? although at those points $f$ is not defined

Comment: It's precisely because $f$ is not defined at these points that we can have asymptotes, in accordance to the etymology.

Comment: To make Bernard's point another way, the definition of _vertical tangent at $a$_ has _two_ conditions:$$\lim_{x \to a} f'(x) = \infty\text { or } -\infty;\quad \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \text{ exists.}$$